# What is wrong with this code? Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I have no clue what is wrong with this code. Error 1004 keeps popping up. I'm new to VBA so maybe I'm missing something on nested for loops. The purpose of this sub is to delete one cell a leave the other too, as in yes-no-no-yes-no-no...

```
Sub hola7()
    Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
For j = columnn To column + userinput
    For i = column To column + userinput Step 3
        If j <> i Then
            Cells(row, j).Selection
            Selection.ClearContents
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Always use `Long` for row and col numbers.

Comment: Always put `Option Explicit` at the top of a module.

Comment: And what is the text of Error 1004? Since you don't provide any details on how to reproduce the environment the code is running in (what is `column`, `userinput` or `row`; how is the worksheet on which this is running constructed, etc.) you should at least provide that...

Answer (score 1):

Use .Select, not .Selection.

```
Sub hola7()
    Dim i As LONG, j As LONG
    For j = column To column + userinput
        For i = column To column + userinput Step 3
            If j <> i Then
                Cells(row, j).SELECT
                Selection.ClearContents
            End If
        Next
    Next
END SUB
```

I'll assume that you have already dimmed and assigned values to column, row and userinput.

Comment: @Alex, Just a side note, you don't need to select it anyway. you can just **`Cells(row, j).ClearContents`**. As you already have the cell in question

Comment: Good job for noticing, I was thinking about differences between `column` and `columnn`

Comment: @Vityata - good catch! I missed that. Suffice to say that there are several issues.

Comment: @Jeeped - actually I guess that `columnn` and `column` are public variables, declared outside the method.

Comment: I think columnn was a typo and yes, I assumed that all undeclared vars were dimmed and assigned values outside of the sub. In any event, not considered 'best practise' since this renders a range's column and row properties useless.

Comment: Yeah, I shudder when people use `reserved` words as variable names.. fraught with danger.. just like when people use `ActiveSheet`.. oooh <shivers down the spine> :)